# extract docx content including mathematical equations with python

Tags: python, markdown, docx, python-docx

I have a docx file that includes "word math" expressions. I want to read the content of the docx file and convert it to markdown so it can be displayed on a web page.
I use python-docx to extract the content and it's working fine, up until it encounters a mathematical expression and then it ignores it. Is there a way to extract the expressions and convert to markdown as well?